# If i want to write multiple requests one by one from client to server, what should I do?

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

For instance, there are several requests in a file, and I read them then send to server line by line by using write function. However, there is only one response from server, and I cannot read the whole requests to server. Is there anyone who can help me to figure out this problem. Thank you so much!

There is server code:

```
    <pre> <code>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sockfd, newsockfd, n;
    unsigned int clientLen;
    char bufferSK[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr,cli_addr;
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    //create an endpoint for bind, listen and accept.
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        printf("Failed to create socket for server!\n");
    }
    bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    //set the address of server.
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port_number);

    //bind the port with server address
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        printf("Error on bind!\n");
    }
    listen(sockfd,port_number);
    printf("\nI am listening for connection\n");
    clientLen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    //using accept function to accept the connection from client
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clientLen);
    if (newsockfd < 0) {
        printf("Error on accept!\n");
    }
    printf("\nI have accepted your connection\n");
    bzero(bufferSK,256);
    n = read (newsockfd, bufferSK,255);
    if (n < 0) {
        printf("Error reading message from socket\n");
    }

    printf("\nThe message from client is: %s",bufferSK);
    n = write(newsockfd, "SERVER: I got your message!\n", 27);
    if (n < 0) {
        printf("Error writing to socket\n");
    }
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

there is client code:

```
<pre> <code>

    FILE *fp_queue;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sockfd, server_port_number, n, connectRes;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    char buffer[256];

    //Three parameters must be provided.
    if(argc != 4){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s server_host_name server_port_number file_path\n",argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    server_port_number = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    //create socket for client.
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        printf("Failed to create socket for client\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        printf("Oops! There is no such host!\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    //set the attributes of server as zeros.
    bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //copy the server address from serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr to server->h_adddr.
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(server_port_number);
    connectRes = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    if (connectRes < 0) {
        printf("Error connection\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("connect successfully\n");
    fp_queue = fopen(argv[3], "r");
    if (fp_queue == NULL) {
        printf("Failed open client file %s\n", argv[3]);
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero(buffer, 256);
    while ((fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp_queue)) != NULL) {
        buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
        printf("buffer is %s\n", buffer);
        n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        if (n < 0) {
            printf("Error write to socket\n");
        }
        bzero(cliBuffer, 256);
        n = read(sockfd, buffer, 256);
        if (n <0) {
            printf("Error read from socket\n");
        }
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Would you mind elaborating upon the problem that you're experiencing?

Comment: Sure! There is a file named client.txt, which contains 4 cities' names. One city per line. Now I am using fgets to read the city name line by line and write function to write the city name from client side to server side. Later, I will parse the city's features on server side.  However, I just can read 3 cities' names into the server side, and the server just can receive one request(city name) from the client side. Therefore, I am confusing how should I do to solve these problems. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 design issues in the code.

The server code receives one request, sends a response and then server terminates. If you want to process more requests over one connection then the server code must contain a loop like a client has. The server code should contain something like

```
while ((n = read (newsockfd, bufferSK, 255) > 0) {
    printf("\nThe message from client is: %s",bufferSK);
    n = write(newsockfd, "SERVER: I got your message!\n", 27);
    if (n < 0) {
        printf("Error writing to socket\n");
        break;
    }
}
close(newsockfd);
```

The next problem is that TCP is a stream oriented protocol and your code does not consider that. The stream orientation means that protocol does not keep message boundaries. When a sender calls `write("a"); write("b")` the receiver may get characters in two separate reads or it may receive 2 characters in one read. To overcome the problem the peers must define some protocol how to determine message boundaries. Usually client sends a message length at begin of message or a control character is used as message boundary or messages have fixed length.

Comment: Thank you so much, Zaboj. You really helped me a lot! I have figured out the first problem. However, I am still confused about the message boundaries you mentioned.  "When a sender calls write("a"); write("b") the receiver may get characters in two separate reads or it may receive 2 characters in one read. " I cannot understand what this means. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: TCP connection is a stream of bytes. It is similar like when you store a byte to a file. When an application calls `write("a"); write("bc")` the reader gets string "abc" and it cannot recognize if the writer did one, two or three writes. If the reader gets "a" in his first read and "bc" in his second read then it is just a coincidence.

Comment: Got you! I have understood what the problem is! I'll look up more materials to figure out this problem! Thank you very much!